# Run command sudo bash with WinSCP .NET assembly

Tags: .net, ssh, sudo, winscp, winscp-net

I am trying to run command `sudo bash` using VB.NET and WinSCP.

I am using this code:

```
Try
    Dim mySessionOptions As New SessionOptions
    With mySessionOptions
        .Protocol = Protocol.Sftp
        .HostName = "10.5...."
        .UserName = "hereGoesUsername"
        .Password = "hereGoesPassword"
        .SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 ......"
    End With
    mySession.Open(mySessionOptions)
    Try
        mySession.ExecuteCommand("sudo bash").Check()
```

Last line gives me an error

> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified.

I can not type password. If I use command line on Windows like `ssh username@host`, then it asks for password, I type in then I can run `sudo bash` and type password again, but how to do it with WinSCP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot provide a password using WinSCP. Read about [technical limitations of WinSCP when executing remote commands](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/remote_command#limitations).

The only option is to allow the user to execute your command without providing the password.

For a general advice, see [How do I change user after login (e.g. su root)?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_su)

The article is about allowing a general access. For your particular case you might be able to enable a specific command only.

*But you didn't really tell us what are you trying to achieve. I suppose that the `sudo bash` is not the final goal. You rather want to execute some command, right? If you give us more details, you might get a more concrete answer.*

Comment: Yes, I want to delete some files, but I dont have permission. When I run sudo bash, type password and then I can delete what i want.

Comment: Then you do not really need `sudo bash`, but `sudo rm`. To restrict abuse of the password-less `sudo` (as described in links in my answer), you can create a script that does the limited+repeating task you want to automate and configure `sudo` to allow only that command.